# cancelar estilos (css) en Child Theme

Tags: css

Estoy trabajando en una web en Wordpress y con un child theme. Quisiera si me pudieran ayudar a determinar el código css que tendría que introducir en el child theme para dejar sin efecto el siguiente código css, que viene del parent theme:

```
.top-nav ul li a:hover {color: #333;}
```

Este código hace que los textos del menú del header, cambien de color cuando el puntero está sobre encima de él.

Si me pudieran ayudar a determinar el código que tengo que incluir en el tema hijo, para que quede anulado el efecto del css anterior :

```
.top-nav ul li a:hover {color: #333;}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que solo puedes agregar una regla con una especificidad mayor en el tema hijo.

Algo como:

```
body .top-nav ul li a:hover {color: #333;} // Aquí cambiar por otro color
```

Pero también depende de donde y como esté definida la regla del tema padre. (En un archivo CSS externo o una etiqueta style, etc...)

Aquí puedes leer un poco más sobre el tema. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascada_y_herencia